# Should questions with a tag in the title be edited to remove tag?

Tags: discussion

I noticed two recent questions had their title prefixed by what is really a tag:

[E-commerce - Is it user-friendly to not provide the option to filter by price?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35102/e-commerce-is-it-user-friendly-to-not-provide-the-option-to-filter-by-price)

[E-commerce - Where should I display 'free shipping if payment by debit card'?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/35129/e-commerce-where-should-i-display-free-shipping-if-payment-by-debit-card)

It seems to me that "E-commerce - " is redundant as both questions are already tagged as e-commerce.

Is there some kind of policy on this site with regard to title conventions that would rule this practice in or out?

If not, I propose that we systematically edit titles to remove tags so that we do not overload titles with redundant data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When it's used artificially as a "category" like the above, yes. If the tag is organically in the title, like "How can I style this dropdown?", it's fine. If it's not part of a normal sentence, kill it.